# ActionMailer looping through nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

How can I loop through the following output code from the console?  Essentially, stories is a nested attribute of an entry and I need to pass "story.content" to a message variable that is used in the email template.

```
//output in firefox console from new.html.erb
name="message[story_attributes][7][content]"

  //new.html.erb  This is the form
  <% for story in @entry.stories %>
    <%= fields_for "message[story_attributes][]", story do |ff| %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= ff.label(:content) %></th>
        <td><%= ff.text_area(:content) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

//internal_email.html.erb - ?????
<% for ... in @message.story_attributes %>
   ?????
<% end %>
```

Comment: solved it by using '.collect(&:content).join("  Story >>>  ").prepend("Story >>>  ")' to collect all the stories and displaying them as a batch instead of individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is not sending the email, try changing deliver to deliver!

also, make sure that you reinitialize the values in InternalEmail class

```
class InternalEmail << ActionMailer::Base    
  def internal_email(message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: "", subject: "")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Dan.  Email will send by leaving out the story.content.  Just trying to figure out how to pass these nested attributes through to ActionMailer.

Comment: The system will look for app/views/internal_email_mailer/internal_email.html.haml . Try to put something in there.